# Page Redirection Issue laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel-5

Hi guys i'm new in laravel, i am creating a page where i can add a user and then it must be redirected to the admin/users(list of users page) but the problem is it redirected to the admin/users but there is no list show or UI of my master page. But when i refresh my page the list will show.

Here's the page where the list must be showed index.blade.php

```
@extends('layouts.admin')

@section('content')


         <table class="table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Email</th>
        <th>Role</th>
        <th>Status</th>
        <th>Created</th>
        <th>Updated</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
  @if($showUsers)
    @foreach($showUsers as $users)
      <tr>
        <td>{{$users->name}}</td>
        <td>{{$users->email}}</td>
        <td>{{$users->role->name}}</td>
        <td>{{$users->is_active == 1 ? 'Active' : 'Not Active'}}</td>
        <td>{{$users->created_at->diffForHumans()}}</td>
        <td>{{$users->updated_at->diffForHumans()}}</td>
      </tr>
    @endforeach
    @endif
    </tbody>
        </table>
@stop
```

My function in AdminUserController

```
public function store(UsersRequest $request)
{
    //

    User::create($request->all());
    // return $request->all();
}
```

Routes.php

```
Route::resource('admin/users', 'AdminUserController');
```

and create.blade.php

```
@extends('layouts.admin')

@section('content')

    {!! Form::open(['method'=>'POST', 'action'=>'AdminUserController@store', 'files'=>true]) !!}

    <div class="form-group">
        {!! Form::label('name', 'Name') !!}
        {!! Form::text('name', null, ['class'=>'form-control']) !!}
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        {!! Form::label('email', 'Email') !!}
        {!! Form::email('email', null, ['class'=>'form-control']) !!}
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        {!! Form::label('is_active', 'Status') !!}
        {!! Form::select('is_active', array(1=>'Active', 0=>'Not Active'), null, ['class'=>'form-control']) !!}
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        {!! Form::label('role_id', 'Role') !!}
        {!! Form::select('role_id', [''=>'Choose Options'] + $showRoles, null, ['class'=>'form-control']) !!}
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        {!! Form::label('file', 'Upload User Image') !!}
        {!! Form::file('file', ['class'=>'form-control']) !!}
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        {!! Form::label('password', 'Password') !!}
        {!! Form::password('password', ['class'=>'form-control']) !!}
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        {!! Form::submit('Create User', ['class'=>'btn btn-primary']) !!}
    </div>

    {!! Form::close() !!}

    @include('includes.formErrors')

@stop
```

Comment: How are you returning the redirect? Your controller doesn't show a proper response being returned.

Comment: How can i do that? I am just learning from some tutorials.Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `redirect` helper method:

```
return redirect('admin/users');
```

Redirecting to a route with data is done like:

```
return redirect()->route('admin/users', ['users' => $users]);
```

Here is the documentation on [redirects](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/redirects)